# celery worker node and celery beat startup configuration

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery worker that executes a bunch of tasks for data loading.  I start up my work node using the following:

```
celery -A ingest_tasks worker -Q ingest --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=3 -f /var/log/celery/ingest_tasks.log
```

I have another application I want to setup as a celery beat to periodically grab files from various locations.  Since my second application is not under the worker node I should be ok just starting the beat like this correct?

```
celery -A file_mover beat -s /my/path/celerybeat-schedule
```

I have never used celery beats before.  From reading the docs they seem pretty straightforward.  However I wanted to make sure this is correct.

Comment: What is exactly the question? Have you tried to do so?

It's been a long time since I used celery, but I recall that you could just start both processes doing `celery -B`

Comment: I think it has changed to celerybeat but same concept.

Comment: best approach.... try it first, THEN ask the question